Error: [GoogleGenerativeAI Error]: Error fetching from ..: [400 ] API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key
i am getiing this error:
Error: [GoogleGenerativeAI Error]: Error fetching from https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent:
 [400 ] API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. 

here is gemini-ai.ts code:
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";   const apiKey = process.env.GEMINI_API_KEY as string ;  const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(apiKey);  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({   model: "gemini-1.5-flash", });  const generationConfig = {   temperature: 1,   topP: 0.95,   topK: 64,   maxOutputTokens: 8192,   responseMimeType: "text/plain", };  export const chatSession = model.startChat({   generationConfig: generationConfig,   history: [], }); .

i think problem is related to environment variable.

What is unclear about "pass a valid API key"?

what are you saying i didnt understand

Use NEXT_PUBLIC prefix:
If you need to access this environment variable on the client side, you should prefix it with NEXT_PUBLIC_. Update your .env.local file:
NEXT_PUBLIC_GEMINI_API_KEY=AIzaSyDyW49l7GXrk0QJmf425uNZgeHY2Sr-JEA

And in your code:
const apiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GEMINI_API_KEY;

TypeScript configuration:
If you're using TypeScript, make sure your next-env.d.ts file includes the following:
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />

declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GEMINI_API_KEY: string;
  }
}

it solve the problem for me now. it is releated to environment variable and typescript.
